# How can I combine 3 queries into one query and the result form look like schedule table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 select queries :

- the result of first for heading of my table.(like : select id, name from cars)
- the second result show left side of my schedule table shows the date of sales (`select date from dates inner join car on date.carid = car.carid where date.date1 > XXX/XX/XX` for example)
- the third result returns the data for inside the table. and it is the price of each car in each date.

But I don't know how to combine them?
 [image]

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Please update your post with sample input data and desired output.

Comment: Please post all 3 queries and some sample output.

Comment: Do you want one column for every car? I think it's only possible with many sub-queries since the car names are values in the table not fields. So you have to write one sub-query / car and then join it on the result table. But I think it's more better to select all the data (see my answer) then format the results with another language (like PHP, Java, Delphi, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like this [Working SQL Server fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37d68/17)

You need either of the following

1. Pivot feature of SQL Server
2. Aggregate function with group-by

**Query:** Pivot feature of SQL Server

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT [SALE_DATE], [CAR_NAME], [COST]
   FROM CARS_SALES
) AS source
PIVOT
(
    MAX(COST)
    FOR [CAR_NAME] IN ([BENZ] , [BMW], [RENAULT])
) as pvt;
```

**Query:** Aggregate function with group-by

```
SELECT SALE_DATE,
      MAX(CASE WHEN CAR_NAME = 'BENZ' THEN COST ELSE NULL END) [BENZ],
      MAX(CASE WHEN CAR_NAME = 'BMW' THEN COST ELSE NULL END) [BMW],
      MAX(CASE WHEN CAR_NAME = 'RENAULT' THEN COST ELSE NULL END) [RENAULT]
FROM CARS_SALES
GROUP BY SALE_DATE
```

---

Both the Queries give an

### output result

as below:

```
SALE_DATE   BENZ       BMW      RENAULT
09/07/2014  (null)     (null)      900
09/08/2014  100        200         300
09/09/2014  400        600         (null)
09/10/2014  700        500         800
```

Comment: Good solution, but not dynamic. So if a new car brand is added to the DB the query need to be updated which isn't very user friendly. But if the asker would like to do it in pure SQL, maybe this is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear, but based on that you've posted, the solution would be something like this:

```
select cars.name, dates.date, dates.price 
from dates 
left join cars on (cars.carid=dates.carid) 
order by cars.name, dates.date;
```

This gets the car's name, price and the date in one query. But I don't understand what your third query is for. If you provide more information I'll update this answer.

Comment: i want to show the cars name in head of table the date in left side and the price inside the table. but this you write it don't show cars name in head of table